# Swift 2.2, RealmSwift - Cannot convert value of type 'Note' to expected argument type Object.Type

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have just started using Realm for a notepad app and saved the array(noteTitles) of a custom class(Note). I made it as an object, but when I use `realm.objectForPrimaryKey(noteTitles, key: "id")` It gives me an error: Cannot convert value of type 'Note' to expected argument type Object.Type. In the class file for note, I have made it as an object.

Here is my ViewController code:

```
var note: Note!
let realm = try! Realm()

@IBOutlet var noteText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var noteTitle: UITextField!

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {


    try! realm.write{

       realm.add(noteTitles)



    }

    print("editing ended")

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.noteText.delegate = self

    realm.objectForPrimaryKey(noteTitles, key: "id")// error here





    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And here is the Class Note Code:

```
 import Foundation
 import RealmSwift


class Note: Object {
    var title = ""
    var content = ""

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

}
```

Thank You in advance for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to [`Realm.objectForPrimaryKey(_:key:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm19objectForPrimaryKeyuRxCS_6ObjectrFTMx3keyGSqPs9AnyObject___GSqx_) should be the type of object you're retrieving. The second argument should the value of the primary key of the object you'd like to retrieve.

For instance, the following will retrieve the `Note` whose `id` property has the value `C5AD8E58-912E-4C32-B67D-748B0621266A`:

```
realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Note.self, key: "C5AD8E58-912E-4C32-B67D-748B0621266A")
```

Comment: It crashes and gives me an error Primary key property 'id' does not exist on object Note. what do I do about this?

Comment: Did I enter the id wrong, or is there something I have to configure?

Comment: The `primaryKey()` function on your `Note` class needs to return the name of the property that you want to be your primary key. It needs to be a property that your class has. In the code you shared above you're saying `id` is your primary key property, but you have not declared a property by that name.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: How would I set the primary key property?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? What have I said so far that you're having trouble with?

Comment: When the text editing is ended, it calls a save uploading it to realm, I want to get it back when the app is opened again and keep it saved

Comment: You said that I need a primary key property, I want to know how to set it.

Comment: The primary key is a property on your model class. You set it in the same way you set any other property.

Comment: How would I set the primary key, could you give me code or an example

Comment: The Realm Swift documentation gives an example of the model with a primary key. This link should take you right to it!  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys

Comment: How do I find out the primary key

Comment: It is giving the error Invalid value 'id' for primary key

Comment: You might not know this, but you don't actually *need* a primary key on every object with Realm. You can often get by without using them at all! I would recommend leaving out the id property for now, and only adding it in if you *really* need it later.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: I want the primary key to retrieve the object, but if there is another way, please tell me

Comment: For example, if you want to sort notes by creation date or edit date, add `creationDate` and `lastModifiedDate` properties to your model (of type `NSDate`) and find them all using `realm.objects(Note.self).sorted("creationDate")`.

Comment: How would I retrieve the array of notes without a primary key?

Comment: You can retrieve *all* notes using `realm.objects(Note.self)`. This will give you an `Results` containing the notes. It's just like an array. You can get the count and access things at a specific index.

Comment: Now it isnt either writing or retrieving because the notes are not saving

Comment: Where would I find results?

Comment: When you create a `Note` object, you must add it to the Realm using `realm.add(myNoteObject)` from within a write transaction.

Comment: I'm really reiterating everything from the docs here, so I would *really* recommend you read this first. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: `Results` is the type of collection returned by the `objects` function on `Realm`.

Comment: Would I put the load onto the notes from results

Comment: `try! Realm().write { try! Realm().add(myNote) }`
will add a note to your realm and
`let allNotes = try! Realm().objects(Note.self)`
will retrieve all your notes.

Comment: It's not returning the notes when I restart the app

Comment: What do I have to do?

Comment: Do I have to do anything to make it an array type variable?

Comment: I suggest you check out sample code or follow a tutorial online. If you're still stuck, please open a new question. Comments are intended to be used for relevant followup.